# VBA temporarily create and delete ListBox after processing array

Tags: vba, listbox

Don't have much experience with forms/listboxes.  The following function aims to remove an array element by passing it to `ListBox` and using `ListBox.RemoveItem` method. What i am struggling with is creating/deleting  `ListBox` object programmatically.  I do know there are ActiveX and Form `ListBox` types but recording a code by adding both manually looks identical:

```
ActiveSheet.ListBoxes.Add(273, 289.5, 72, 71.25).Select
```

Here is the attempted function:

```
Function ArraylessElement(arrIn As Variant, ElemNo As Integer) As Variant
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'removes i element from 1D array by assigning to ListBox
    'returns 1D array w/ Transpose
    ''''''''''''''''''
    Dim lBox As ListBox
    With ActiveSheet
        Set lBox = .ListBoxes.Add(261, 279.75, 72, 71.25)
        lBox.List = arrIn
        lBox.RemoveItem (ElemNo - LBound(arrIn) - 1) '(LBound) of a ComboBox/ ListBox is 0.
        ArraylessElement = Application.Transpose(lBox.List)
        lBox.Delete
    End With
End Function
```

I'm getting

> Unable to set the list property of the ListBox class

error on `lBox.List = arrIn` line.

PS. I did see a `DeleteArrayElement` function at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm which i will use if i cannot get mine working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586797/delete-an-item-in-an-array

Comment: You would be much better off using a collection if you want to dynamically remove/add elements. Even better, the `Items` property of a collection is an `Array`. So you can get an array back from the collection once you are done with it.

Comment: @BrandonBarney. Interesting, thanks. I have not thought about it. I guess the advantage compared to creating a new array is no ReDim for Collection.  As I see the advantage of ListBox, however, would be a direct assignment while the collection i'd need to loop through to pass an array. Would not that be slower for a large enough array?

Comment: @Vrun I work with collections that are hundreds of thousands of items in size and I havent noticed a difference considerable enough where I have had issues. It definitely depends on what you are working with, and how big you array is though. You would be hard pressed to find an instance where the performance cost of a `Collection` outweighed using an `Array` though, even if just because a `Collection` is intuitive and requires far less operations (on the surface)  than an `Array`.

Comment: @BrandonBarney except `VBA.Collection` has no `Items` property...

Comment: @Mats Mug For some reason I thought it did. A dictionary would work then (that definitely has items and keys, both arrays), but far less convenient. Or you could easily write a function to take turn it back into an array. Definitely takes some steam out of that approach though.

Comment: dictionary keys were unique i thought.   and going back to a new array is pretty much what Chip Pearson had on the link i initially enclosed.  so going back to my original post,  fixing a listbox error, anyone? :)